# My php loop is not populating my database with MYsql

Tags: php, mysql, loops, increment

I have the following Mysql tables and PHP code.

MySQL : I select from Store table the amount of stores. Which returns my store list.

I also have a cashup table with info

PHP :
A loop takes place where for numberofdays is suppose to be the days in a month.

In the while loop I do a SQl select that returns my values out of cashup table according to the date and the store.

In the loop I increment my days to allow cycle through all my stores for 31 days to return the cashup sum values.

```
//loop days
$numberofdays = 31;
$monthyear = NOV_2016;
$x = 1;
        //loop days
        do {
            //string days info
            $thedate =  $x . '_' . $monthyear;

            if (strlen($thedate) == 10){
                    $thedate = '0' . $thedate;
                    }
                //Do select 
                mysql_select_db($database_localhost, $localhost);
                $query_showr = "select sum(cashup_cash) from cashiercashdata where cashup_date LIKE '$thedate' and cashup_store = '$store'";
                $showr = mysql_query($query_showr, $localhost) or die(mysql_error());
                while ($row_showr = mysql_fetch_assoc($showr))
                        {
                            //loop through record rows
                            foreach($row_showr as $row)
                                {
                                ///////$insertday = "recon_d" . $x . "_received";   
                                echo " Store : " .  $store . " Counter : " .  $x . ' : ' . gettype($x) . ' : ' . $row . ' : ' . gettype($row) . '<br>';
                            mysql_query("
                            update bankrecon
                            set recon_d10_received = '$row'
                            WHERE recon_store = '$store'
                            and recon_month = '$monthyear'
                            ");
                    }
                        }
$x++;
        } while ($x <= $numberofdays);
```

PHP :
A loop takes place where for numberofdays(integer) is suppose to be the days in a month.

In the while loop I do a SQl select that returns my values out of cashup table according to the date and the store.

In the loop I increment my days to allow cycle through all my stores for 31 days to return the cashup sum values.

This echo's my information correctly on display but my update in the loop only inserts info if the numberofdays is set to static 10;

```
Store : centralpark Counter : 10 : integer : 56277.40 string
Store : ficksburg Counter : 10 : integer : 42698.14 string
Store : kroonstad Counter : 10 : integer : 28486.70 string
Store : maitland Counter : 10 : integer : 55988.40 string
Store: od Counter : 10: integer 41412.10 string
```

It works correct on display but not updating the destination table.
Can anyone please explain to me why the looping of the numberofdays info does not trigger the update for the column but if the numberofdays is static it updates.

[image]

Comment: print the SQL query, you will get the error.

Comment: Unfortunately print the sql and echoing the value gives the same results. The info echos correctly with the values. meaning my query is correct. The update in the inner loop updates the destination table correctly but only if the numberofdays var is set to static 10 int. The iteration with the while loop or a for loop which dynamically changes the value for some reason causes the update statement not to respond correctly

Answer (score 0):

Now, it's hard to know exactly without knowing what your destination table looks like, but I'd guess it has something to do with your UPDATE statement.

```
update bankrecon
    set recon_d10_received = '$row'
    WHERE recon_store = '$store'
    and recon_month = '$monthyear'
```

Specifically this bit: `set **recon_d10_received** = '$row'`

Is that perhaps telling the table to update only day 10?

Comment: Currently I was testing my update to recon_d10_received. The purpose of the selects is to populate a grid for 30 stores with cashup info for every day of the month. The $x increment will dynamically change on every iteration of the loop. The Update works fine when a static integer of 10 is given to the numberofdays. But when the loop iterate over the where $x = 10 with the loop the info still echo correctly but the update ignores the value ti insert to the norlan varchar column in the destination table.

Comment: Please find the table insert and the files on a server for clearer understanding. The db to insert to  is called cashup.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/0rlsm73uqy7p42o/bankrecon.sql?dl=0
https://www.dropbox.com/s/bh6srw7wic4y89k/cashiercashdata.sql?dl=0
https://www.dropbox.com/s/55nyzuu9i2vhlv1/store.sql?dl=0
https://www.dropbox.com/s/9ly02qoyw88f51r/gridtest.php?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

**two example tables sql:**

```
CREATE TABLE `bankrecon` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `recon_d10_received` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `recon_store` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `recon_month` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `data and store` (`recon_store`,`recon_month`,`recon_d10_received`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=20 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


CREATE TABLE `cashiercashdata` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `cashup_cash` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cashup_date` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cashup_store` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**and php itself:**

```
session_start();

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "someuser", "somepass", "somedb");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

    $store = 'somestrome';
    $numberofdays = 31;
    $monthyear    = 'NOV_2016';
    $x            = 1;
    //loop days
    do {
        //string days info
        $thedate = $x.'_'.$monthyear;

        if (strlen($thedate) == 10) {
            $thedate = '0'.$thedate;
        }
        $showr = $mysqli->query("select sum(cashup_cash) as cashup_cash from cashiercashdata where cashup_date LIKE '$thedate' and cashup_store = '$store'")->fetch_assoc();
        if(!is_null($showr['cashup_cash'])){
            $sql = " INSERT INTO bankrecon (recon_d10_received,recon_store,recon_month) VALUES ('".$showr['cashup_cash']."','$store','$monthyear') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE recon_d10_received='".$showr['cashup_cash']."'";
            $mysqli->query($sql);
            echo " Store : ".$store." Counter : ".$x.' : '.gettype($x).' : '.$showr['cashup_cash'].' : '.gettype($showr['cashup_cash']).'<br>';
        }


        $x++;
    } while ($x <= $numberofdays);
```

Keep in mind:

- Change $store var
- Keep UNIQUE KEY on columns `recon_store`,`recon_month`,`recon_d10_received` on use [insert-on-duplicate](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html).
- Change db connection code

Also use this php code to see  more errors:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```